# Изменение объектов JS

Tags: javascript

Почему здесь при модификации объекта из функции, не меняется исходный объект?  Спасибо!!

```
var objs = {
  className: 'menu'
};

function news() {
  objs.className = 'new menu';
  console.log(objs);// 'new menu'
}
console.log(objs);//'menu'

news();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы изменился объект в функции, надо её (функцию) запустить. Запускаете вы функцию только после `console.log(objs);`, поэтому изменений не видите. А вот если напишите так:

```
news();
console.log(objs);
```

то увидите, потому что будете просматривать объект после отработки функции.

```js
var objs = {
  className: 'menu'
};

function news() {
  objs.className = 'new menu';
  console.log(objs);// 'new menu'
}

news();
console.log(objs);
```